# when i try to convert data into PDF i got error : Undefinde variable $incomes in pdfview.blade.php

Tags: php, pdf

this is my pdfview.blad.php

```
<div class="container">
<br/>
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf'])}}">Download PDF</a>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Income name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
     @foreach ($incomes as $key => $income)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
        <td>{{ $income->income_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $income->income_amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $income->income_des }}</td>
        <td>{{ $income->income_date }}</td>
    </tr>
     @endforeach
</table>
</div

> Blockquote
```

---

this is my pdfcontroller where i write a code for download PDF link and codding of convert file in PDF format

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;

class pdfcontroller extends Controller
{

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    $incomes = \DB::table("income")->get();
    view()->share('income',$incomes);

    if($request->has('download'))
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');

        return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
    }

    return view('pdfview')->with(compact('incomes'));
}
}
```

---

in route.php i had written the below code,
       Route::get('/pdfview',array('as'=>'pdfview','uses'=>'pdfcontroller@pdfview');

Comment: change `view()->share('income',$incomes);` to `view()->share('incomes',$incomes);`

Comment: it's working.. thank you so much :) @B.Desai